# How do you increment a count while using the sleep function?

Tags: c, signals, sleep

Hey guys I seem to be lost. I am supposed to be able to increment a count in a child inside an infinite loop, and to have the count be printed every time the parent sends a signal, which should be every 1 second. I wrote my code but I thought that after using fork, the child and parent processes run at the same time, however this is not the case so I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. Any help would be great

Comment: *I wrote my code...* show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing should work in theory.

Writing parallel code can be tricky, especially using `fork()`, if you're not familiar with the process.

Here is my suggestion:  add a bunch of debug prints throughout your code, for example:

```
int pid = fork();
if(pid == -1) {
    printf("Fork failed!\n");
} else if (pid) {
    printf("I'm the parent!\n");
    // Do stuff
    printf("Parent exiting\n");
    exit(0);
} else {
    printf("I'm the child!\n");
    // Do stuff
    printf("Child exiting\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Then you can see if your program is behaving the way it should.

Also add a `printf()` statement to your signal handler so you can make sure it is being called.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would like to show you my code, could you tell me how you sent that code so it could stay in that form? When i copy ans paste my code it bunches up after i send it

Answer (score 1):

The child process should be able to just run `sleep()`, and have the parent send `SIGALRM` to wake it up. Perhaps you made the child sit in a [busy loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), consuming so much CPU that the parent didn't get to run as predicted.

Of course, answers to questions like these are way better if you show your code.

Comment: I'm trying to paste my code but it doesn't stay in the form that i paste it in. Is there something special I need to do before i paste my code in? By the way, I am the one that made the question.

Comment: @user1357998 Not sure, there might be a problem with the question length and your account's relative newness, perhaps. You can try using pastebin or some other such site for temporary storage, and hope that someone edits it in, assuming it's not too long, of course. And your name is right there, both on your comment and on your question. :)