# How do you increment a count while using the sleep function? (in C language)

Tags: c, signals, sleep

Hey guys I seem to be lost. I am supposed to be able to increment a count in a child inside an infinite loop, and to have the count be printed every time the parent sends a signal, which should be every 1 second. I wrote my code but I thought that after using fork, the child and parent processes run at the same time, however this is not the case so I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. Any help would be great

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
int count = 0;//global count variable

void catch(int signal){
printf("Ouch! - I got signal %d \n", signal);
printf("count is %d\n", count);
count = 0;
}

int main(){
int pid;
int sec=0;
pid = fork();
int count1 = 0;
(void) signal(SIGALRM, catch);
if(pid==-1){
    printf("error\n");
}
else if(pid==0){//if child
    while(1){//while loop to increment count while parent to sleeping
    count = count + 1;
    }
    //pause();

    }
else{//parent
    sleep(1);//1 second pause
    raise(SIGALRM);//send alarm
    count1 = count1 + 1;
    if(count1>=5){
        return 0;
    }
    exit(0);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328956/how-do-you-increment-a-count-while-using-the-sleep-function

Comment: please use the edit button to make changes to your question and do not just asked basically the same question again

Answer (score 0):

`raise` sends the signal to yourself (i.e., the parent) not to the child. Use `kill(child_pid, SIGALRM)`.

Answer (score 0):

After you use fork the variable of the two processes are at different memory location. So when you raise a signal in the parent process, what is printed out is the "count" variable of the parent process. You can print the "count" inside the loop of child process to see it increase